# Kong to have anonymous routing through jwt global plugin

Tags: jwt, anonymous, kong

I have been using Kong db-less 1.4.1, runing on Kubernetes (OpenShift)

I have configured (enabled) JWT plugin as global to be used for all rest APIs behind the Kong but I also need to have anonymous in the same plugin as exceptions, I created the jwt plugin by below yaml.

```
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
config:
anonymous: “this is an example of consumer_id”
kind: KongPlugin
metadata:
labels:
app.kubernetes.io/instance: kong
app.kubernetes.io/name: kong
global: ‘true’
name: global-jwt
namespace: iot-kong
plugin: jwt
```

Moreover I have also created `KongConsumer` and `KongCredential`.

This plugin works perfectly but when I add anonymous in this configuration, it doesn’t work anymore

Please do me a favor and send me an practical example to solve my problem.